# Include Hive query in a Pyspark program

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Hive and I need to create a new Hive table via HiveContext in a Pyspark program.

How to do that ? Please help me with this issue .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlCtx= HiveContext(sc)

test_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'metric1', 10), (2, 'metric2', 20), (3, 'metric3', 30)], ['id', 'metric', 'score'])
test_df.registerTempTable("df_table")

sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE df_hive_table AS SELECT * from df_table")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can I run any type of Hive query inside sqlCtx.sql ? Or is it a SparkSQL ?

Comment: Spark SQL almost support most of the Hive queries, except few. They are very well documented in this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/compatibility/hive.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!